# How can I access the list of ParameterDefinition objects sent to the "properties" method in jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

We're using Jenkins 2.303.1.

We mostly use Jenkins scripted pipeline.  I'm aware of the fact that declarative is supposed to be preferred.  That ship has sailed. We can't change right now, and it would be a very large effort to convert.

At the top of our shared library, we have a block that starts like this:

```
properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [
    [$class: 'hudson.model....ParameterDefinition', name: '...',     defaultValue: ""],
    ...
]]])
```

I have a need to have code that can examine these definition objects and extract information from them.  I am able to extract all of the build actions, and I was able to find the ParametersAction in that list, and I can iterate through all the parameters in that action.  Unfortunately, when I call "getDefinition()", which the javadoc does defined as deprecated, it fails with an "UnsupportedOperation" exception, which might be happening intentionally, to prevent calling deprecated methods.  I need to confirm whether there is any way I can call this method and get the definition.

I'm also aware that "Accessing ParameterDefinition is not a good idea." because apparently it "may change any time."  I don't know what "any time" means.  I'm intending to access this information right at the start of the build.  It's not clear to me under what circumstances these objects might change.